When did Vegeta achieve Super Saiyan 3?
In Dragon Ball Daima, Vegeta turns Super Saiyan 3. After this Bulma says he trained a lot.
Is it ever show in the manga/movies/series etc. when Vegeta turned Super Saiyan 3 for the first time?
